# Flatness conditions in terms of commuting vector fields

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am new to Riemannian manifolds and want help finding references to prove the following fact, I read in Lee's Riemannian manifolds, and Introduction to smooth manifolds:

$M$ is a compact $n$-manifold with a global basis of commuting vector fields, then there is a flat Riemannian metric on $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are a global basis of commuting vector fields on $M$.
Let $g$ be the Riemannian metric on $M$ which makes $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ orthonormal;
that is,
\begin{equation*}
 g = \alpha_1 \otimes \alpha_1 + \dotsm + \alpha_n \otimes \alpha_n ,
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n$ is the dual basis of one-forms.
Recall the Koszul formula: If $U,V,W$ are vector fields, then the Levi-Civita connection is determined by
\begin{align*}
 2g(\nabla_UV,W) & = U\bigl(g(V,W)\bigr) + V\bigl(g(U,W)\bigr) - W\bigl(g(U,V)\bigr) \\
 & \quad + g([U,V],W) - g([V,W],U) + g([W,U],V) .
\end{align*}
Since $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are orthonormal and commuting, each summand in the Koszul formula for $g(\nabla_{X_i}X_j,X_k)$ vanishes.
Therefore $\nabla_{X_i}X_j=0$ for all $i,j \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n\}$.
Plugging this into the definition of the Riemann curvature tensor implies that $g$ is flat.